# How can I prevent an item in a CSS grid layout from growing to accommodate its content?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert scrollable content into a CSS grid layout, without the grid layout slot containing the scrollable content automatically growing in an attempt to accomodate that content.

I would like the size of the grid item to be the same as it would have been without the scrollable content.

I have found that setting the height of a container for the scrollable content to a fixed value gives the desired results, but I don't know in advance what that value should be. Perhaps it's possible to calculate the value in JavaScript, but I would prefer not to unless it were the only way. I want it to be based on the space that would have been available had that content not existed.

In the example below, when you click the "Large amount of output" button, the height of the `#right1` div grows from 300px to a larger value. I would like the height of `#right1` to be unchanged when clicking this button. I essentially want to make it behave as if the height of `#output_container` were set to a fixed value. But I don't want to manually specify the fixed value, because I want it to use all of the available space. The height of `#output_container` is currently set to 100%. That makes it the correct size, unless the unless its child div (`#output`) forces it to grow. I want to prevent this type of growth, because that content is scrollable. It's not necessary to make the `#output_container` larger to see that content.

I've tried using grid and flex layouts inside of `#right1` to specify that `#output_container` should use the remaining vertical space in `#right1` under everything else. However, `#output_container` still grows based on the `#output` div inside of `#output_container` and I don't want it to do that.

```js
function showSize(selector) {
  const a = document.querySelector(selector);
  const p = a.querySelector('p');
  p.textContent = `${getComputedStyle(a).width} x ${getComputedStyle(a).height}`;
}

function showSizes() {
  showSize('#left');
  showSize('#right1');
  showSize('#right2');
  window.setTimeout(showSizes, 100);
}

function writeOutput(lines) {
  const output = document.querySelector('#output');
  let text = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    for (let j = 65; j < 91; j++) {
      text += String.fromCharCode(j);
    }
    text += "\n";
  }
  output.textContent = text;
  output.scrollTop = output.scrollHeight;
}

document.querySelector('#small').addEventListener('click', () => writeOutput(5));
document.querySelector('#large').addEventListener('click', () => writeOutput(50));
writeOutput(5);
showSizes();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#output_container {
  /* Setting the height to 100% makes it the right size, unless its child div forces it to grow.
     I want to prevent this type of growth, because the child content is scrollable.
  */
  height: 100%;
  /* Setting the height to a fixed size works, but I don't know in advance what the size should be in order for the Output panel to be be size that it would have been if this content were not there. */
  /* height: 170px; */
  background: lightseagreen;
}

#output {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 83%);
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pre {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.pre:after {
  /* Allows user to see a trailing line break. */
  content: '';
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "left right1"
    "left right2";
}

#left {
  grid-area: left;
  background: lightskyblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  // min-height: 800px;
}

#grid > div {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#right1 {
  grid-area: right1;
  background: seagreen;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

#right2 {
  grid-area: right2;
  background: lightsalmon;
  min-height: 300px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

button {
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="left">
    <p></p>
    <button id="small">Small amount of output</button>
    <button id="large">Large amount of output</button>
  </div>
  <div id="right1">
    <p></p>
    <h1>Output</h1>
    <div id="output_container">
      <div id="output" class="pre"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right2">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `position: relative;` to the container that I didn't want to grow (`#output_container`) and `position: absolute; width: 100%;` to its child (`#output`), whose content was causing the growth of the parent container.

```js
function showSize(selector) {
  const a = document.querySelector(selector);
  const p = a.querySelector('p');
  p.textContent = `${getComputedStyle(a).width} x ${getComputedStyle(a).height}`;
}

function showSizes() {
  showSize('#left');
  showSize('#right1');
  showSize('#right2');
  window.setTimeout(showSizes, 100);
}

function writeOutput(lines) {
  const output = document.querySelector('#output');
  let text = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    for (let j = 65; j < 91; j++) {
      text += String.fromCharCode(j);
    }
    text += "\n";
  }
  output.textContent = text;
  output.scrollTop = output.scrollHeight;
}

document.querySelector('#small').addEventListener('click', () => writeOutput(5));
document.querySelector('#large').addEventListener('click', () => writeOutput(50));
writeOutput(5);
showSizes();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#output_container {
  /* Setting the height to 100% makes it the right size, unless its child div forces it to grow.
     I want to prevent this type of growth, because the child content is scrollable.
  */
  height: 100%;
  /* Setting the height to a fixed size works, but I don't know in advance what the size should be in order for the Output panel to be be size that it would have been if this content were not there. */
  /* height: 170px; */
  background: lightseagreen;
  position: relative;
}

#output {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 83%);
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pre {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.pre:after {
  /* Allows user to see a trailing line break. */
  content: '';
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "left right1"
    "left right2";
}

#left {
  grid-area: left;
  background: lightskyblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  // min-height: 800px;
}

#grid > div {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#right1 {
  grid-area: right1;
  background: seagreen;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

#right2 {
  grid-area: right2;
  background: lightsalmon;
  min-height: 300px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

button {
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="left">
    <p></p>
    <button id="small">Small amount of output</button>
    <button id="large">Large amount of output</button>
  </div>
  <div id="right1">
    <p></p>
    <h1>Output</h1>
    <div id="output_container">
      <div id="output" class="pre"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right2">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```